# How to get only the file name in the variable and not the complete path shell script?

Tags: shell

```
mainFile=$(find /home/INVENT/custREAD -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -mmin 300)
```

I m using the above line in my shell script to fetch the file from the location /home/INVENT/custREAD for today's date and put it in the variable mainFile

But when I echo this variable, I see:

```
 /home/INVENT/custREAD/filename.txt
```

But I want that only the file name to be in the variable,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`basename`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) to your `find` call

```
mainFile=$(find /home/INVENT/custREAD -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -mmin 300 -exec basename {} \;)
```

Though I will warn that if you have more than one match your variable will contain multiple paths which will cause things to break (this is independent of my change to your `find` call).

Comment: I tried this and it worked too. Now the variable $mainFile has value : filename.txt.gz, but this is I think only assigning the name of the file to the variable rather than pointing/referring to the file. Is it correct ?

Comment: A variable cannot point to a file, it can merely contain the name of a file. What do you mean by “point to the file”?

Comment: ok I get it but its failing in the further check if it do if [ "$mainFile" ] its not recognizing it.

Comment: Based on this and another recent question, it sounds like you are trying to ask multiple minimal questions towards writing a script. Unfortunately, it seems like to give a useful answer the scope of what you are trying to achieve needs to be present. I would recommend asking another question where you explain all of what you are trying to do, show what you currently have tried, explain what you expect the output to be, and then state the output you are getting instead, and then ask for advice on how to achieve your actual goal.

Comment: @Aviator, `if [ "$mainFile" ]` only tests that the variable is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`s `printf` directive.

```sh
mainFile=$(find "$dir" -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -mmin 300 -printf '%f\n')
```

---

Alternately, you can use shell parameter expansion to strip off the path:

```sh
mainFile=$(find "$dir" -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -mmin 300)

mainFile=${mainFile##*/}    # remove the longest prefix ending with slash
```

Comment: Always liked the `"%f"` method as it is handled by `find` directly without more required.